# Web Scraping problem through python, can't read html file?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Been web scraping a while with Python and recently I came across this problem.
BeautifulSoup doesn't seem to be able to read the html file.

For example i'm trying to scrape from this website
https://www.thetvdb.com/series/initial-d/episodes/4889010

And this my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url_episode = 'https://www.thetvdb.com/series/initial-d/episodes/4889010'
print(url_episode)
getdetail_episode = requests.get(url_episode)
soup = BeautifulSoup(getdetail_episode.content,'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

I was able to scrape data from other links, but not this one.

What else should I be doing to get this working?
Thanks

*UPDATE*
So I checked with Relp.it and other online python compilers, the code worked. WTF?

And it's not working with my Sublime Text or Python IDLE compiler on my computer?

I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I think I figured it out. 
The whole trouble was caused by the delay of data loading from the webpage, causing the IDE to think there's no data to scrape.

Ended up using requests-html instead of BeautifulSoup to resolve them.

so pretty much like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
url_episode = 'https://www.thetvdb.com/series/initial-d/episodes/4889010'
getdetail_episode = session.get(url_episode)
soup = BeautifulSoup(getdetail_episode.content,'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```